# AWS Lambda Java SDK Connect Timeout Issues

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I have a java program that I want to invoke an AWS Lambda:

```
String database = "database-name";
String name = "table-name";
String lambdaName = "hive-nebula-directory-lambda-qa";
DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain defaultProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
AWSCredentials defaultCreds = defaultProvider.getCredentials();

AWSLambda lambdaClient = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion("us-east-1")
        .withCredentials(defaultProvider)
        .build();
String payload = "{'RequestType':'Database.Table','Request':'" + database + "." + name + "'}";
InvokeRequest request = new InvokeRequest().withFunctionName(lambdaName);
InvokeResult response = lambdaClient.invoke(request);
System.out.println(response);
```

The program fails on the invoke statement with the error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request:
Connect to lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 
[lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.209.234.7, 
lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.86.49.162, 
lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.88.170.138, 
lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.236.156.247, 
lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.85.154.34, 
lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.88.193.25, 
lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.88.112.102, 
lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/107.23.102.90] 
failed: connect timed out
```

I have gotten the lambda to invoke correctly with the python boto3 library and directly with the AWS CLI so I'm sure the default credentials are set up correctly.

Any ideas why the connection is timing out?

Comment: You haven't added your payload in InvokdeRequest.
It should be invokeRequest.withFunctionName("lambdaName").withPayload(payload);